# Is it possibile to reverse engineer a partial R2 squared from a multivariate regression table?

Tags: multiple-regression, sample-size, statistical-power, r-squared

I don't have any data, so I'm trying to extract a partial R-squared for one of the predictors from a linear multiple regression, in order to calculate the sample size for a regression study I would like to conduct. The partial R-squared will be fed into Gpower to calculate f2, and then the sample size.
I have these values: intercept, standardized betas, standard errors, the overall coefficient of determination, and the number of observations.
My initial approach was to transform the standardized beta into Pearson's r and then calculate the partial R-squared, but this approach is incorrect as it would yield the R-squared of a regression with a single predictor, not a partial one.
In your opinion is it possibile, in R, to reverse-engineer the partial R2squared i am interested in?
If yes, how to do that? If not, why?
Thanks to whoever responds."

Edit:
@Harrell: i have imperfect understanding of many nuances of statistical anlysis. I just thought that maybe there would be out there some tranformations involving the whole output, which i'm not aware of.
@whuber: yes, if i had the matrix i could just have fed it into Gpower. Unfortunately i don't.

Comment: Assuming the standardized $\beta$ is adjusted for other covariates, why would a transformation of it correspond to a marginal $R^2$?

Comment: A dimension-counting argument establishes that it *might* be possible to find the partial R squared with 4 or fewer variables but should *not* be possible with more than 4 variables, because there are just too many unknowns to solve for.  You're essentially trying to reconstruct the (inverse of the) variance-covariance matrix of the predictors.

Comment: @whuber Yes , that was my thought